# disabled combobox when click checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was tried to disable, but there is some problem, first, it can't save db because disabled. second, the disable is not working when the combo box has **class=chosen-select** from another javascript. the disabled working when I delete the **class='chosen-select'** but it can't save the database. here's the code.

```
//checkbox

<div class='side' style='top:4px'><input name='check' id='check' type='checkbox' class='regular-checkbox' onclick="run();" <?php if ($row['check']=="1"){echo "checked";} ?>/>&nbsp;
    <label for="check"></label>
</div>
<div class="labelbox"></div>

//combobox

<div class='side'>
    <select id="cmbobox" name="cmbobox" style="width:100px;"" class="chosen-select">
        <option value="">Kosong</option>
        <option value="3">3 Bulan</option>
        <option value="6">6 Bulan</option>
        <option value="9">9 Bulan</option>
        <option value="12>1 Tahun</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="labelbox"></div>

//javascript disabled combobox

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    function run(){
        var b = document.getElementById("cmbobox");
        if(document.getElementById("check").checked == true) 
        {
            b.disabled = true ;
        }
        else
        {
            b.disabled = false ;
        }
    }
</script>

//javacript chosen-select

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var config = {
        '.chosen-select'           : {},
        '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
        '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
        '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Data tidak ketemu'},
        '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
        jQuery(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP/MySql - It is HTML and Javascript with a dash of JQuery

Comment: ... and please use the script snippet button so people can give it a go

Comment: sory, my bad. i